# What are the code convention for parameters/return values (collections)

Tags: c#

I had a little discussion with a friend about the usage of collections in return/input values of a method. He told me that we have to use
- the most derived type for return values.
- the least derived type for input parameters.

So, it means that, for example, a method has to get a ReadOnlyCollection as parameter, and as return a List.

Moreover, he said that we must not use List or Dictionary in publics API, and that we have to use, instead Collection, ReadOnlyCollection, ... So, in the case where a method is public, its parameters and its return values must be Collection, ReadOnlyCollection, ...

Is it right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding input parameters, it's generally more flexible to use the least specific type.  For example, if all your method is going to do is enumerate the items in a collection passed as an argument, it's more flexible to accept IEnumerable<T>.

For example, consider a method "ProcessCustomers" that accepts a parameter that is a collection of customers:

```
public void ProcessCustomers(IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
{
   ... implementation ...
}
```

If you declare the parameter as IEnumerable<Customer>, your callers can easily pass in a subset of a collection, using code like the following (pre-NET 3.5: with .NET 3.5 you could use lambda expressions):

```
private IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersByCountryCode(IEnumerable<Customer> customers, int countryCode)
{
    foreach(Customer c in customers)
    {
        if (c.CountryCode == countryCode) yield return c;
    }
}

... 
ProcessCustomers(GetCustomersByCountryCode(myCustomers, myCountryCode);
...
```

In general MS guidelines recommend not exposing List<T>.  For a discussion of why this is so, see [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/04/27/faq-why-does-donotexposegenericlists-recommend-that-i-expose-collection-lt-t-gt-instead-of-list-lt-t-gt-david-kean.aspx) from the Code Analysis (FxCop) team.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with not returning or using  List or Dictionary as parameters in API's because it really limits the developer targeting the API. Instead returning or passing IEnumerable<> works really well.

Of coarse, all of this depends on the application. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your friend read:
[Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)

It is a great book, and it covers questions like this in detail.